# Android Studio WebView App Through Proxied DNS

Tags: android, webview, dns

I'm wondering if its possible to create an Android Studio WebView App that connects to a custom DNS Server such as 1.1.1.1 , Before connecting the User to the WebView Website.

Example :
User -> Router -> ISP Server -> 'WebviewApp' -> **Custom DNS (1.1.1.1)** -> 'WebviewAppURL' -> ISP Server -> Router -> User

Been pondering around the webs and couldn't find leads